Jacobian of the vector reflection operator
While re-deriving some equations relevant to Monte-Carlo path tracing (specifically, the probability distribution of sampling a specific light direction from Sampling the GGX Distribution of Visible Normals), I stumbled upon the need to compute the determinant of the Jacobian of the operator that reflects a vector $V$ from the surface orthogonal to a vector $H$, with respect to the vector $H$:
$$L(H,V) = 2(H\cdot V)H - V$$
$$\det \frac{\partial L}{\partial H} = ?$$
as a function on the unit sphere.
To make it more malleable, I rewrote it as
$$L(H,V) = 2(H\cdot V)H - (H\cdot H)V$$
which is the same function if $\|H\|=1$, but is also a homogeneous function of $H$ of order 2, which means that it is a product of radial and spherical components, and thus the determinant of the spherical part of the Jacobian is just the determinant of this function viewed as
$$L(\cdot,V) : \mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$$
divided by the derivative of the radial part (which is the derivative of $R^2$ evaluated at $R=1$, which is simply $2$).
Now, to compute the 3D Jacobian, I transformed the function into matrix form
$$L(H,V) = 2HH^TV - VH^TH$$
and applied the usual matrix calculus to obtain
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial H} = 2(H^TV\cdot I+HV^T-VH^T)$$
This matrix looks quite special: neglecting the factor of 2, its diagonal elements are just $H\cdot V$, while the off-diagonal part is antisymmetric (and seems to be a matrix form of the bivector $H\wedge V$).
However, computing its determinant by hand proved to be quite tedious. Using sympy I was able to obtain the formula
$$\det \frac{\partial L}{\partial H} = 8\cdot H^2V^2(H\cdot V) \quad\quad(1)$$
After substituting $\|H\|=\|V\|=1$ and dividing by 2 (the radial part of the Jacobian), we get $4(H\cdot V)$, which coincides with the result from the paper linked above.
Now, my question is: how can one obtain equation (1) without fully expanding the Jacobian in coordinates?

My thoughts:

It seems that one can treat the $HV^T-VH^T$ as two rank-one updates for the matrix $H^T V\cdot I$, and use the rank-one determinant update formula twice to compute the determinant. However, given that the problem is so geometric in nature, is doesn't feel like the right approach. Also, since the rank-one update formula requires the adjugate of the updated matrix, this hardly seems easier than computing the determinant entirely from scratch.

Using the Clifford algebra $\operatorname{Cl}(\mathbb R^3)$ we can express our reflection using the Clifford product simply as $L=H\cdot V\cdot H$, and the derivative (as a linear operator on the tangent space of the algebra) is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial H}(\delta) = H\cdot V\cdot \delta + \delta \cdot V \cdot H$. The Clifford algebra formulation seems to be somehow related to the $H\cdot V + H\wedge V$ expansion we've seen earlier. However, I don't know how this can help in computing the determinant.



Shouldn't $L(H, V) = V - 2(H \cdot V)H$?

@Kakashi It depends on what you mean by reflection (i.e. does it stay in the same halfspace relative to H or if it flips), and on the orientation of V (i.e. does it point towards the origin, like the direction of a light ray, or in the opposite direction). In my case, it points from the origin (opposite the light ray), which is common in graphics calculations, and the reflection is on the same side of the plane (like a light ray reflected by a mirror).

Define
$$
A = (H \cdot V)I + H V^T - V H^T.
$$
Let $H,V$ be unit vectors.
Let $Q=H \times V$ be a vector orthogonal to them.
Consider $A$ in the $H,V,Q$ frame:
$$ A H = 2(H \cdot V)H - V ,$$
$$ A V = H, $$
$$ A Q = (H \cdot V)Q. $$
It is now clear that $A$ only performs a scaling in the $Q$ direction and some rotation in the $H,V$ plane.
Thus,
$$\det A = H \cdot V.$$

Interesting approach, thank you! It took me a while to realise why it is a rotation in (H,V) plane. I'll wait for a day or two and accept the answer.

To see that $A$ is a rotation in the $H,V$ plane consider the following.
Define $B$ as the reflection that maps $BH=V$ and $BV=H$.
We then check that the mapping $AB$ satisfies $ABH = H$ and $ABV = 2(H \cdot V)H - V$, which is also a reflection.
All in all, we see that $A = (AB)B^{-1}$, which is the composition of two reflections, and thus a rotation.

Nice, thank you!
